# Pentaho Reporting: Date picker parameter not parsing into user console web page report

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am developing a report using the Pentaho Report Designer. One of the parameters is Date Picker. When I try to publish the report in pentaho user console, I get an error message saying - "Error parsing parameter information". However, when I change the date parameter type to any other option like drop down or single value list or text box, it gets published successfully without any issues.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: which version your using and also let me know its CE or EE

Comment: click on edit parameters and attach the screen-shot.

Comment: I am using Community Edition and the version is 7.1.0.0-12

Answer (score 0):

For some reason , date picket doesnt work as intended in the community edition. Try using the Text box option.